# Ember fire not synchronizing properly when clearing an array

Tags: firebase, emberfire

I am storing an array of objects in firebase and using the `push` method from the server as seen below:

```
  firebaseRef.child('colors').push(body, (error) => {
    if(error) {
      res.send(500, error);
    }
    else {
      res.send(200);
    }

    return next();
  });
```

And on the client I am using:

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('color');
}
```

I have an operation where I want to clear the array and I'm currently using `set([])` as seen below:

```
firebaseRef.child('colors').set([], (error) => { ... });
```

If I look at the data from the management portal I can see the colors node and all elements are removed; however, the ember client still shows all the items in the array. Even after I add an item to the array to make it a length 1 it would still show perhaps 24 if it had 23 previously.  It is only after I completely refresh the client does it properly recognize the length of the array.

How do I reset the array in a way which the client stays synchronized without having to remove each element one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Your clearing the data from firebase directly while avoiding the ember data store. To do this correctly you have to do it the "Ember Way" by clearing it from the data store locally which will then push these same changes to firebase for you.

Figure out how to clear the color models from ember data and you should get the results you expect